# Replace one row and column in a matrix with a row and column from another matrix

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have two correlation matrixes. I want to replace row/column 5 of matrix 1 with row/column 5 of matrix 2.

```
matrix1 <-matrix(c(1:25),5, 5) 
colnames(matrix1)<-c("1","2","3","4","5") 
rownames(matrix1)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

Looking like this (of cause with other numbers.)

```
   1  2  3  4  5
A  1  2  4  0  0
B  2  1  0  0  3
C  4  0  1  0  0
D  0  0  0  1  0
E  0  3  0  0  1
```

How can I replace row 5/column E from matrix1 with row 5/column E from matrix2?

I tried to work with it like a dataframe but that lead to nothing.

Comment: `matrix1[5, 5] <- matrix2[5, 5]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking to replace a single element located at row 5 and column 5, or are you asking 2 questions: how to replace row 5 and how to replace column 5?

Assume 2 matrices:

```
matrix1 <-matrix(c(1:25),5, 5) 
colnames(matrix1)<-c("1","2","3","4","5") 
rownames(matrix1)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")

matrix2 <-matrix(-c(1:25),5, 5)
```

Replace the single element at (5,5):

```
matrix1[5,5] = matrix2[5,5]
```

Replace row 5:

```
matrix1[5,] = matrix2[5,]
```

Replace column 5:

```
matrix1[,5] = matrix2[,5]
```